# Two snippets of code with the same logic work different in C# and Python

Tags: c#, python, complex-numbers

I'm stuck: snippet of code, written in C# and Python, which does the same thing works different. What is wrong?

C# snippet:

```
Complex[] myFunction(Complex[] first, Complex[] second)
{
    int N = first.Length;
    Complex[] result = new Complex[N];
    for (int m = 0; m < N; m++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < N; h++)
        {
            if (m + h < N)
                result[m] += first[h] * second[m + h];
            else
                result[m] += first[h] * second[m + h - N];
        }
        result[m] /= N;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Python snippet:

```
def count_correlation_by_formula(first, second):
    rest = [0] * SAMPLES
    for m in range(SAMPLES):
        for h in range(SAMPLES):
            if ((m + h) < SAMPLES):
                rest[m] += first[h] * second[m + h]
            else:
                rest[m] += first[h] * second[m + h - SAMPLES]
        rest[m] /= SAMPLES

    return rest
```

I've checked Python snippet on Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 - the same output. In my tests `N = SAMPLES = 16`. So, size of `first` and `second` in both versions is always 16.

Why `result` and `rest` have different values after the performing these functions?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `N = first.Length - 1;`?

Comment: No, I don't mean it. Why should we do -1 ? It is not index.

Comment: What type is first and second?  Are they strings, integers, single, double?  It appears that first and second are arrays (not complex) that you are converting to an array of complex numbers.  Fix the types of first and second.

Comment: Which one is correct?

Comment: first and second are arrays of complex numbers in both versions. In C# they have `System.Numerics.Complex` type, in Python built-in type (when I generate them I use `complex()` cast)

Comment: Perhaps then `for (int h = 0; h < N - 1; h++)`

Comment: I still don't understand why. N is a size of array. N = 16, we start from 0 till 15.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is the Complex Number class itself. It could be managing the floating point numbers differently than what it does in Python. For testing purposes, you could try changing from Complex to double and see if the values match better. If they do, then it is something "wrong" with the Complex class.